# How do I import only a few lines from a python script?

Tags: python

I am making a Twitter python script, in which I want to use it on a few accounts.

I have my accounts tokens stored on a file called `twitter_tokens.py`. Here is its contents:

```
# Account 01 
OAUTH_TOKEN = "aehbrstnfbdtfjhnbw45rjnsdty"
OAUTH_SECRET = "hrbesfdxhbtfgnrstnn"
CONSUMER_KEY = "e vaeior23nrguna564564erugnpnapnbobmna"
CONSUMER_SECRET = "resbsoirnbveioranbkjsrenb"

# Account 02 
OAUTH_TOKEN = "3409gjhr89b4jrngoe"
OAUTH_SECRET = "4w5henrtydjm67rjh34ahy"
CONSUMER_KEY = "45wuhe564e56jmruyfkhmr"
CONSUMER_SECRET = "6ejtydhrsyhet7ulkyftfge4rdyhjt"

# Account 03 
OAUTH_TOKEN = "h487ur6tyrgw45r7u78tkjhes"
OAUTH_SECRET = "srhtrhesrdvm80ej"
CONSUMER_KEY = "f349w0jyg09esmvsrinhmbiwo3am"
CONSUMER_SECRET = "43wg8934ngoilnvqop34ngebvsoerinb"

# Account 04
OAUTH_TOKEN = "vserimgiseomvioq34nmopigb"
OAUTH_SECRET = "resboidfmvzmvmdrgpomrh"
CONSUMER_KEY = "rmes89hfuivsbrldbnau9rgbw5"
CONSUMER_SECRET = "reabsredzbvaerdgma8erionmgbiosrtn"
```

Then, on the top of my script I have this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from twitter import Twitter, OAuth, TwitterHTTPError

execfile('twitter_tokens.py') #import tokens

t = Twitter(auth=OAuth(OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_SECRET,
            CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET))
[...]
```

The code above wouldn't work as the variables will conflict. What I would like to learn how to do is, lets say I want my script to use the "**Account 01**". If I import only the first 5 lines of `twitter_tokens.py`, it would work. Then, if I wanted to use the script on the "**Account 02**", I could import the 5-11 lines.

Is there a way to do this in python?
Also, my main concern is: Is this a good way to do what I want to do? What would be a better way to do this? I don't want to have a single `.py` file for each twitter account I have.

Thanks.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do with a single variable accounts and dictionary inner dictionary

```
 accounts = {
        'acc1': {
            'OAUTH_TOKEN': "aehbrstnfbdtfjhnbw45rjnsdty",
            'OAUTH_SECRET': "hrbesfdxhbtfgnrstnn",
            'CONSUMER_KEY': "e vaeior23nrguna564564erugnpnapnbobmna",
            'CONSUMER_SECRET': "resbsoirnbveioranbkjsrenb"
            }
        , 'acc2': {
            'OAUTH_TOKEN': "3409gjhr89b4jrngoe",
            'OAUTH_SECRET': "4w5henrtydjm67rjh34ahy",
            'CONSUMER_KEY': "45wuhe564e56jmruyfkhmr",
            'CONSUMER_SECRET': "6ejtydhrsyhet7ulkyftfge4rdyhjt"
            }
        , 'acc3': {
            'OAUTH_TOKEN': "h487ur6tyrgw45r7u78tkjhes",
            'OAUTH_SECRET': "srhtrhesrdvm80ej",
            'CONSUMER_KEY': "f349w0jyg09esmvsrinhmbiwo3am",
            'CONSUMER_SECRET': "43wg8934ngoilnvqop34ngebvsoerinb"
            }
        }
```

and instead of using `execfile` use the `import`

```
from config import *

print(accounts['acc1']['OAUTH_TOKEN'])
```

Comment: Such a strange place for a comma. Python is liberal enough to accept an extra trailing comma within data structures.